# Why do I get many Moose warnings when I start Catalyst?

Tags: perl, moose, catalyst

I am having an issue (Catalyst related) apparently with Moose/Class::MOP. Starting my server I get the following output... (shown below in all its glory)

> The alias and excludes options for role application have been renamed -alias and -excludes at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Meta/Role/Application.pm line 26
>     Moose::Meta::Role::Application::new('Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToRole', 'excludes', 'ARRAY(0x9645568)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Meta/Role.pm line 416
>     Moose::Meta::Role::apply('Moose::Meta::Role=HASH(0x95b3368)', 'Moose::Meta::Role=HASH(0x9446d90)', 'excludes', 'ARRAY(0x9645568)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 133
>     Moose::Util::_apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Role=HASH(0x9446d90)', undef, 'MooseX::Getopt', 'HASH(0x9454a08)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 87
>     Moose::Util::apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Role=HASH(0x9446d90)', 'MooseX::Getopt', 'HASH(0x9454a08)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Role.pm line 26
>     Moose::Role::with('Moose::Meta::Role=HASH(0x9446d90)', 'MooseX::Getopt', 'HASH(0x9454a08)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Exporter.pm line 294
>     Moose::Role::with('MooseX::Getopt', 'HASH(0x9454a08)') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/ScriptRole.pm line 8
>     require Catalyst/ScriptRole.pm called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 113
>     Class::MOP::__ANON__() called at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 71
>     eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 67
>     Try::Tiny::try('CODE(0x93c2910)', 'Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x93bba38)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 124
>     Class::MOP::load_first_existing_class('Catalyst::ScriptRole') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 136
>     Class::MOP::load_class('Catalyst::ScriptRole', undef) called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 109
>     Moose::Util::_apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x8fc9378)', undef, 'Catalyst::ScriptRole') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 87
>     Moose::Util::apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x8fc9378)', 'Catalyst::ScriptRole') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose.pm line 58
>     Moose::with('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x8fc9378)', 'Catalyst::ScriptRole') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Exporter.pm line 294
>     Moose::with('Catalyst::ScriptRole') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Script/Server.pm line 14
>     require Catalyst/Script/Server.pm called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 113
>     Class::MOP::__ANON__() called at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 71
>     eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 67
>     Try::Tiny::try('CODE(0x8f6dc38)', 'Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x8f8d1c8)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 124
>     Class::MOP::load_first_existing_class('Catalyst::Script::Server') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 136
>     Class::MOP::load_class('Catalyst::Script::Server') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 18
>     Catalyst::ScriptRunner::run('Catalyst::ScriptRunner', 'Jamaica', 'Server') called at script/boca_server.pl line 8
> The old Moose::Util::MetaRole API (before version 0.94) has been deprecated at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util/MetaRole.pm line 16
>     Moose::Util::MetaRole::apply_metaclass_roles('for_class', 'Catalyst::Controller', 'metaclass_roles', 'ARRAY(0x97bdff8)', 'method_metaclass_roles', 'ARRAY(0x97ab9f0)', 'wrapped_method_metaclass_roles', 'ARRAY(0x981d650)') called at /usr/share/perl5/MooseX/MethodAttributes.pm line 32
>     MooseX::MethodAttributes::init_meta('MooseX::MethodAttributes', 'for_class', 'Catalyst::Controller', 'metaclass', undef) called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Exporter.pm line 355
>     Moose::Exporter::__ANON__('MooseX::MethodAttributes') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Controller.pm line 10
>     Catalyst::Controller::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Controller.pm line 10
>     eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Controller.pm line 10
>     require Catalyst/Controller.pm called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst.pm line 16
>     Catalyst::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Controller.pm line 10
>     eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Controller.pm line 10
>     require Catalyst.pm called at /home/bobek/dev/build_7.2/mvc/Jamaica/script/../lib/Jamaica.pm line 17
>     Jamaica::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Controller.pm line 10
>     eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Controller.pm line 10
>     require Jamaica.pm called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 113
>     Class::MOP::__ANON__() called at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 71
>     eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 67
>     Try::Tiny::try('CODE(0x8fb3230)', 'Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x969fee0)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 124
>     Class::MOP::load_first_existing_class('Jamaica') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 136
>     Class::MOP::load_class('Jamaica') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/ScriptRole.pm line 61
>     Catalyst::ScriptRole::_run_application('Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x969d748)') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Script/Server.pm line 181
>     Catalyst::Script::Server::run('Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x969d748)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP/Method/Wrapped.pm line 48
>     Class::MOP::Method::Wrapped::__ANON__('Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x969d748)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP/Method/Wrapped.pm line 89
>     Catalyst::Script::Server::run('Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x969d748)') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 20
>     Catalyst::ScriptRunner::run('Catalyst::ScriptRunner', 'Jamaica', 'Server') called at script/boca_server.pl line 8

I am new at Catalyst (and I do like it, I just want to successfully get it up and running). I have checked the latest versions of Moose and Class::MOP and they are up to date (as far as CPAN is concerned).

Hopefully someone familiar with Moose has seen this before. Any suggestions or a place to start checking would be appreciated.

Michelle B.

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of `boca_server.pl`?

Comment: Thanks Eric. line eight ....
    Catalyst::ScriptRunner->run('Boca', 'Server');

Catalyst creates automagically creates this. :-)

Comment: How are you installing Moose and Catalyst? There should have been a warning at install time regarding version incompatibility.

Comment: Thanks Ether! I just did a simple install through CPAN. No warnings though.

Comment: For this particular issue we failed to provide the right warning in Makefile.PL in one Moose version. It's quite possible there was none.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're running an old version of Catalyst. This issue has been fixed in commit [r13516](http://dev.catalystframework.org/svnweb/Catalyst/revision?rev=13516) and is already available on CPAN as of version 5.80026 (5.80028 is latest and recommended).

Catalyst was using some deprecated feature of Moose, which just recently started warning.

Comment: THANK YOU rafl! I just needed to upgrade Catalyst. I know that was fairly obvious and I thank you. (as well as Eric and Ether)

Comment: would you take a peek at my new reply. There are some version dependency issues in the current stuff and most of it seemed to have your name on the releases. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, you're right, the current Cat stuff has a fairly broken dependency chain.  You can see from the current pass/fail on the CPAN for 5.80030 that fails are much higher than normal.

There are several bumps depending on the state of your current modules/versions. This worked for me this morning (I'm not sure if it's overkill)-

```
cpanm -v namespace::clean
cpanm -v namespace::autoclean
cpanm -v B::Hooks::EndOfScope
cpanm -v Package::Stash
cpanm -v Class::MOP Moose MooseX::Types
cpanm -v MooseX::Role::WithOverloading::Meta::Role::Application

cpanm -v Catalyst Catalyst::Devel
```

And if you're using Config::General for your configuration, this is a good idea too:

```
cpanm -v Config::General
```

If you get those in and it won't start, just read the stack trace (backwards) looking for names or missing functions/methods. Anything you see as a problem, upgrade. It's a "stable" kit but it's a collection of moving targets and everything has to line up.

Comment: There's an issue with some of the modules you mentioned, not with others. Those are caused by changes in Package::Stash. When you upgraded Package::Stash, its Makefile.PL has warned you about that and told you which module you need to upgrade. Also it installed a `package-stash-conflicts` program for you to check which modules you still need to upgrade in case you missed the Makefile.PL notice.

Comment: @rafl, thank you for the info (and the hard work, I do appreciate it!). I don't think having the average user jump through this kind of hoop is the right way to go about this though. I can do it but most wouldn't/couldn't. The FAIL rate for Cat tests on 5.80030 is > 12% right now while 5.80029 was < 1%.

Comment: If you have alternative solutions on how to work around the lack of conflicts support in the CPAN toolchain, please tell us.

Comment: @rafl: Heheh. I know it can be a tarpit. I actually did not get a "package-stash-conflicts" installed; not sure why, could have been me.

Comment: @rafl: Looks like the wedge in this case is the lack of version declaration for namespace::clean/namespace::autoclean in the Makefile.PL dependencies for MooseX::Role::WithOverloading. They're both zero now (in 0.09). I'm not positive what version fixes the breakage. Mine were 3 100ths back IIRC. Perhaps these would actually be better addressed in the Moose space(?).